# Quick Sort C++ Implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, quick-sort

I'm learning C++ and algorithms myself, and as training I had to write quicksort by myself.All feedback on coding style/clarity and concepts are welcomed!

```
int QuickSort(int *Array, int start, int end)//Recursive function that sorts array
{
    int Wall = start;//Variable that will hold pivot position before recursive calls and tracks indexes                 
    int Temp = 0;   //Variable used for swaping array members
    if (start < end)//Exit condition
    {
        for (int Index = start; Index < end; Index++)
        {
            if (Array[Index] <= Array[end])
            {
                Temp = Array[Wall];
                Array[Wall] = Array[Index];
                Array[Index] = Temp;
                Wall++;
            }
        }
        Temp = Array[end];
        Array[end] = Array[Wall];
        Array[Wall] = Temp;
    QuickSort(Array, start, --Wall);//Calling racursion for left of the pivot
    QuickSort(Array, ++Wall, end);//Calling recursion for right of the pivot
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is off-topic since it contains code known to the author to be broken (stack-overflow exception).  Voting to place this question on hold until it's fixed.

Comment: I don't know - a stack overflow when there are 10,000 elements? Given errors I've seen in other code here that passed muster, I wouldn't consider that a deal breaker, personally.

Comment: @Adler11th - why do you think it takes up too much memory? Aside from stack space, it works in-place. That seems pretty memory efficient to me.

Comment: I ran new tests in the evening. It's really inconsistent with results I had when I was posting this code. Now it seems to run much quicker and can handle arrays size even at 100 000(adding one more zero will cause stack overflow). Maybe its VS2017 ??IDK. However any feedback on coding itself will be welcomed. I never had any friends/co-workers which can undertand and write code thus I don't have any input on how well/bad I am doing. Thank you

Comment: @Snowhawk, I believe by too much OP meant around 1MB. I wouldn't take the observations literally most of the time. Voting to leave open. Probably OP stumbled upon a very bad partition.

Comment: Those increment/decrement operators look weird in `QuickSort(Array, start, --Wall);    QuickSort(Array, ++Wall, end);` Are you sure the `Wall` value passed in the second call is the one you wanted to pass...?

Comment: @Incomputable This is a conversation better had on Meta CR if you want to have it. Simply put, "Questions containing [broken code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3650) or asking for advice about [code not yet written](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3651) are off-topic, as the code is not ready for review."  From the [broken code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3650) meta post, stating "If the array size is 10,000, I get a stack overflow massage." means the code isn't working as the OP expected and makes this question off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is fairly impressive. I don't know if I would have done this in-place if I sat down to do this today. That said, I do see a few things you could improve.

## Naming

I think your variable names could use some work. Why did you choose `Wall`? That name just doesn't strike me as useful in this context.

I notice that you're mixing capitals and lowercase letters for the first letter of your variables. Typically variables start with a lowercase letter and type names start with an uppercase letter. You don't necessarily have to follow that convention, but you should be consistent.

## C++

The only line of code in this that differentiates it from C is the print statement, which I assume is just for debugging. If you `#include <utility>` you get some very useful functions. (You'll need to `#include <algorithm>` if you're using C++ that pre-dates C++11.) For example, `std::swap()` will swap 2 values for you without the need to write out 4 lines of code:

```
std::swap(Array[Wall], Array[index]);
```

does the same thing as:

```
int Temp = 0;   //Variable used for swaping array members
...
            Temp = Array[Wall];
            Array[Wall] = Array[Index];
            Array[Index] = Temp;
```

Also, you don't need `std::endl` where you've used it. That will flush the buffer which will slow things down. You can simply use:

```
std::cout << Wall << "\n";
```

And if you're really paranoid, you can add a single call to:

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

after `QuickSort` returns;

## Recursion

As you found, when you have a deeply recursive function, it can eventually eat up the entire stack if you're not careful. Luckily, you can eliminate recursion in many cases. I modified yours to remove the recursion by adding a simple `std::queue` and putting the ranges in the queue instead of calling back into the function. First, I made a simple `struct` to hold a range of indexes to sort:

```
struct Range {
    int start;
    int end;
    
    Range(int newStart, int newEnd) : start(newStart), end(newEnd) {}
};
```

Then I updated the function to use a `std::queue` and the new `Range` type:

```
void QuickSort(int* array, int start, int end)
{
    std::queue<Range>  queue;
    queue.push(Range(start, end));
    while(!queue.empty())
    {
        Range next    = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        
        int start = next.start;
        int end = next.end;
        int Wall = start;
        if (start < end)
        {
            for (int Index = start; Index < end; Index++)
            {
                if (array[Index] <= array[end])
                {
                    std::swap(array[Wall], array[Index]);
                    Wall++;
                }
            }
            std::swap(array[end], array[Wall]);
            queue.push(Range(start, --Wall));
            queue.push(Range(++Wall, end));
        }
    }
}
```

I kept most of your code, but used `std::swap` and removed the recursion.

To be honest, I didn't think the performance of your version was bad at all. It seemed to work plenty fast for me.

Comment: Thank you! I will work on on the issues you pointed out. I ran test again and this time it was much different from what I had when I was posting this code. Idk maybe it was just VS2017 doing some wierd things which I don't understand yet.

Comment: Hmm... you are correct. It used to be in <algorithm> pre-C++11, but somehow, when I went to compile my changes, I was getting an error on that line that seemed to go away with `#include <stdlib.h>`. Must have just been a coincidence. I will correct that.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about recursion depth, as it only scales \$O(lg(N))\$on average, \$O(N)\$ in the worst-case, which can be avoided in the OP's solution by choosing a better pivot (e.g. median as pivot, random element as pivot). However, in your solution, you'd queue up \$O(N)\$ ranges in every case (i.e. you always have a worst case), as you are basically doing a level-order traversal instead of a pre-order traversal. Maybe us a stack instead of a queue?

Comment: Yes, I realized at 5AM that I had intended to use a stack. Regardless, the reason I brought it up was because the OP's description made it sound like he may have been hitting a stack overflow from the recursion. That's why I mentioned it.

Comment: Please note that the use of queues does not solve the problem with the unbalanced partitioning, it just shifts the memory consumption from a limited stack space to a much more capacious heap. If you worry about the memory consumption in the partitioning's worst case, just push the longer partition to the stack and iterate processing the shorter one with `while(start<end){...}. In the recusive implementation: recurr with the shorter part and after return proceed with partitioning the longer one. This way the worst memory cost is kept at \$\log_2 N\$.

Answer (score 4):

#### Iterators

Currently you can sort anything that uses `int*`. But an iterator is a data type that has the same behavior as a pointer (when used in appropriate contexts). But there are other types that are iterator; so using them makes your code much more generalized.

```
template<typename I>
int QuickSort(I begin, I end)
```

Now your sort is generalized for any type that supports iterators (a pointer can be used as an iterator into a C-Array). But you can now also sort vector's lists and any other standard container type.

#### Don't Declare variables before you use them

```
int Temp = 0;   //Variable used for swaping array members
```

This is declared way at the top.
You should declare variables just before you need them. This helps in the readability of the code (as I don't have to scroll back to the top of the function to find out what the code type is).

Also it prevents you wasting an instruction initializing a value that you will never use (here you init to zero but is that just a waste). If you declare at the point of usage you avoid that waste.

```
            int Temp = Array[Wall];      // declaration and initialization
            Array[Wall] = Array[Index];
            Array[Index] = Temp;
```

Also when object becomes more complex and they have constructors. Initializing them only when you need them can become a good savor of space time.

#### Prefer pre-increment

You seem to use post increment. This is fine when the type is an integer. But in C++ code you usually see this with iterators and here the post increment is slightly less efficient than the pre-increment.

By using pre-increment you will always have the most efficient version and when your code is altered (and it will be) the person changing it does not need to go and check all the places where you use increment and change it from post to pre.

Answer (score 4):

## Implementation

- Since the return value `0` isn't used anywhere, why not make the return type `void`?
- Inconsistent naming: Some variable names start with a capital letter, some don't.
- Naming: `Wall` is even described as pivot position in the comment. Why not name it `Pivot`?
- Swapping elements could be done using `std::swap`, or barring access to a standard library, delegated to a similar function.

## Design

- While the function length isn't too bad, the partition logic could be extracted into its own function for readability.
- Usual C++ standard library implementations work with iterators. `QuickSort` could be designed to accept those.
- `QuickSort` only works for elements of type `int`. This could be extended for other types (e.g. by using a template).
- Usually, ranges are expected to not include the last element. `end` however is included into the range to be sorted. While no problem on its own, it might make sense to adhere to the usual convention. After all, which is clearer: `QuickSort(vec.data(), 0, vec.size())` or `QuickSort(vec.data(), 0, vec.size() - 1)`?

## Performance / Correctness

- `QuickSort` repeatedly includes the current pivot in the recursive calls (the second recursive call, to be exact), while it doesn't have to be included. After all, we already know its final position.
- During the partition step, `QuickSort` copies every element that is equal to the pivot to the first "half". These copies aren't necessary! If they are equal to the pivot, it doesn't matter if they are left or right of the pivot.
- `QuickSort` uses a bad pivot: In the worst case (e.g. all elements reversed, or, thanks to the issue above, all elements equal), it's going to recurse up to depth \$O(N)\$. This, combined with a small choice of random elements, is very likely the source of your stack overflow issue (try an array of all `0`s against an array with all distinct elements!). With a better choice of pivot (e.g. median, median-of-three or random) and partitioning algorithm (e.g. no copying of elements equal to the pivot), you'd never get (or at the very least, be much less likely to get) the worst case behavior.
- The quick sort algorithm has low complexity, so it's fast for huge data sets. However, for small data sets, other sorting algorithms (even bubble sort!) can be faster. If the difference between `start` and `end` drops below that threshold, it would very likely be better for performance to use another sorting algorithm to sort that subset.

Comment: `If they are equal to the pivot, it doesn't matter if they are left or right of the pivot.` That depends on your definition of correctness. If you want your sorts to be stable then they need to be copied. This is more useful when you upgrade to a more interesting type than int but it is nice if your sort is already stable before you generalize.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Not necessarily: you'd only need to guarantee that the position of the pivot relative to the other equal elements doesn't change. In the OPs case, that's only happening because of that specific choice of pivot and him copying all those equal elements. Both choices aren't benefiting the runtime performance (in fact, they are the reason for the stack overflows!). ...

Comment: @LokiAstari: ... That said, quicksort usually isn't stable (nor is it expected to) - it's strengths are \$O(log N)\$ average memory usage and \$O(N log N)\$ average runtime complexity. Making quicksort stable inherently requires it to lose at least one of those qualities (everything has its price)! Also, if you require stability, there are other established sorting algorithms that provide that within well specified parameters, e.g. mergesort.

Comment: Regarding the first item headed `Performance / Correctness`: I don't see "the" pivot included (*`++Wall`*)(, even the spelling of `recursion` looks correct(ed)). The way to preclude O(n) space for limits of unhandled ranges is to recurse on the smaller partition, but iterate on the larger  (Sedgewick (in ["Implementing Quicksort programs"](https://doi.org/10.1145%2F359619.359631)?)).

Comment: @greybeard: the pivot is included in the second call, because `++Wall` only "cancels out" `--Wall` in the call before (so it's pointing to the pivot again). // To get \$O(log N)\$ space complexity (aka recursion depth), the partitions should be relatively even in length. If perfectly halved at each step, you'd need \$(log_2(N)\$ recursion calls. However, in case of the most uneven split (\$N - 1\$ one side, other \$0\$), you'd need \$N\$ calls total (because every call only takes 1 element from the range).

Comment: True about `Wall`. If you rephrase `partitions should be relatively even in length` to *partitions which may be (substantially) larger than half what was partitioned should not be processed recursively*, you see where *iterate the larger partition* comes from and leads to.

Comment: @greybeard: Oh, I get it. That would work, too, to prevent \$O(N)\$ recursion depth. But it would still take \$O(N^2)\$ runtime in the worst case if the pivot choice doesn't get improved.